# Sails JS: Pass parameter to toJSON

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

The sailsjs model attribute method toJSON is very handy for processing model attributes before sending back to client. However, this method does not take any parameters and I cannot pass additional information to the method that can be used for processing attributes.

In my particular case, I need to check if I should send an attribute by comparing logged in user id (req.user.id). E.g.

```
toJSON: function () {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  var result = {};
  if (req.user.id === 123) {  // How can I access req from inside toJSON?
    // do something here ...
  }
}
```

I could not find a way to access the req parameter from inside toJSON. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails does purposely not expose the req attribute as a global so there is no way to access it from within toJSON: 
[How to access session variables outside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833573/in-sails-js-how-to-access-session-variables-outside-controller)

Depending on the functionality you are trying to achieve you might be able to use policies instead: [How to access request object in sails js lifecycle callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370497/how-to-access-request-object-in-sails-js-lifecycle-callbacks)

In a similar case, I found myself using a workaround instead. You can add the id of the logged in user in your controller to the model:

```
YourModel.findOne().exec(function (err, yourModelObject) {

    yourModelObject.loggedInUserId = req.user.id;
    res.send(yourModelObject);

});
```

It is then accessible in your toJSON method and you could use it like this:

```
toJSON: function () {
    var obj = this.toObject();
    var result = {};

    if (obj.loggedInUserId === 123) {  
     // do something here ...
    }

    delete obj.loggedInUserId;

    return obj;
}
```

It is a little bit of a hack, but it worked for me. Be careful that a user can't somehow set the same value on the model (for example by using  `schema: true` in your model) in question, to prevent security holes in your code.